# Apply jQuery Form Submit Validation to only 1 out of 2 Submit Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have 2 Submit buttons on my form:

```html
<div class="text-center">
  <button type="submit" name="buttonType" value="saveSelected" id="save" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>&nbsp; &nbsp;
  <button type="submit" name="buttonType" value="declineAll" class="btn btn-danger">Decline All</button>
</div>
```

I've recently added some validation to the form submission, but I only want it to apply to the 'Submit' button not the 'Decline All' button. Here's my script:

```js
$("form").submit(function(event) {

  if ($('#productID').val() == '') {

    $("#productID_Error").show();
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;

  }

});
```

Is there a way I can restrict the form validation only fire when the first Submit button is clicked?

Comment: where is your form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some solution here .

1. please change the of Decline All button like  attribute : type='button'
2. use below process

   ```
   $("#save").click(function (e) {
      // put your validation here 
      $("form").submit();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can change second button type submit to button

```
<button type="button" name="buttonType" value="declineAll" class="btn btn-danger">Decline All</button>
```

Using above approach form validation only fire when the first Submit button is clicked

Comment: I still need the form to be submitted when they click the Decline All button - if I change the type to 'button' it doesn't appear to actually do anything or submit the form?

Comment: but your question is you want submit form only submit button not decline all button

Comment: @user982124 I dont't think you would be submitting anything to server side on declineAll button

Answer (score 0):

You can change button type from `submit` to `button`, see below code

```js
$("form").submit(function(event) {

  if ($('#productID').val() == '') {

    $("#productID_Error").show();
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;

  }

});
```

```html
<div class="text-center">
  <button type="submit" name="buttonType" value="saveSelected" id="save" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>&nbsp; &nbsp;
  <button type="button" name="buttonType" value="declineAll" class="btn btn-danger">Decline All</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I still need the form to be submitted when they click the Decline All button - if I change the type to 'button' it doesn't appear to actually do anything or submit the form?

Comment: Then you can use the second way which @RajuMalli suggested as answer.

Comment: Yes agree with you @Novice, This is another option

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div class="text-center">
      <button type="submit" name="buttonType" value="saveSelected" id="save"      class="btn btn-success" id="submitButton">Submit</button>&nbsp; &nbsp;
       <button type="submit" name="buttonType" value="declineAll" class="btn btn-danger">Decline All</button>
</div>



$("#submitButton").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  if ($('#productID').val() == '') {

    $("#productID_Error").show();
     event.preventDefault();
     return false;


} else{
    $("#yourForm").submit();
  }
});
```

validatde the form on click event on submit button

Comment: I still need the form to be submitted when they click the Decline All button - if I change the type to 'button' it doesn't appear to actually do anything or submit the form?

Comment: add click event on the button.and submut form if it is valid.check the updated code

Answer (score 0):

Since `Button type` for both the button is same, hence the conflict. 
Instead, you may try to change `button type` from `submit` to just `button`, something of this type:

```
<div class="text-center">
  <button type="submit" name="buttonType" value="saveSelected" id="save" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>&nbsp; &nbsp;
  <button type="button" name="buttonType" value="declineAll" class="btn btn-decline">Decline All</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have to add a function on click event of one of your button and inside that function you have to complete your validation tasks. Please check the code below -

**HTML**

```
<div class="text-center">
    <button type="submit" name="buttonType" value="saveSelected" id="save" class="btn btn-success"  onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>&nbsp; &nbsp;
    <button type="submit" name="buttonType" value="declineAll" class="btn btn-danger">Decline All</button>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function myFunction(){
    alert( "Your validation code" );
}
```

It is only going to be triggered if the specific button is pressed. On the other buttons triggering it wont be executed. And there wont be any problem of form submission as well.

Hope it helps...:)